# Maintain hovering color when clicking on a button

Tags: css, button, hover

On 3 buttons at the end of each of my post page, I would like to put a hover color when people are clicking on one of them. Here is an example of the 3 buttons: 
In my PHP file, these 3 buttons are located here: [Post Page](http://socatchy.net/percy-lau-mystery-and-creation/)

```
<ul class="tabnav-widget ui-tabs-nav">
   <li class="ui-tabs-selected">
      <a class="" href="#tab1-widget">written by</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a class="" href="#tab3-widget">Related Posts</a>
   </li>
   <li class="">
      <a class="" href="#tab4-widget">In this Category</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

But I don't know what CSS class I have to modify and which CSS code to add in order to maintain a hovering color when clicking on one of the three buttons.

I thank you in advance, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for `a:active` ?

Comment: You can use the :hover and :active psuedo-selectors.

Comment: Agreed, a:active should work providing you remain on the same page, obviously if you link off to another page state is lost and you are presented with a new set of links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this in the CSS

```
.tabnav li:hover, .tabnav-widget li:hover {
    background: #color;
}
```

Additionally, if you would like to change the color when the button is pressed down, use `:active`.

Add something like this:

```
.tabnav li:active, .tabnav-widget li:active {
    background: #color;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works !
But after the cursor leaves the navigation square, whether it's hovered over or clicked on, the background color changes back to it's original state. I would like the color to stay the same color as the hovered state when the current page is showing. I've made an exhaustive search but nothing seems to work. Thanks for your help and for your time !

Comment: @David That wouldn't be possible in CSS. Hover is meant to only work on hover, not the other way around.